# Determine if any of the values in a set of variables match the value in another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

For each person in my dataset (1 row per person), I am trying search a set of variables (months, so in my example Jan - Jul) to see if any of them matches the value in a different variable (follow-up month). I want to create a new variable that says yes or no there is a matching value in the set of variables with the 1 variable.

Basically I am trying to create a timeline for a follow-up visit. I have 'Have' and 'Want' data sets below.

Thank you!

HAVE:

| ID | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | Jul | Follow-up month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 2 | 3 | 4 | NA | NA | NA | 4 |
| 2 | NA | NA | NA | 4 | NA | NA | NA | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | NA | 3 | 4 | 5 | NA | NA | 5 |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 6 | 7 | 9 |

WANT:

| ID | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | Jul | Follow-up month | Follow_up_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 2 | 3 | 4 | NA | NA | NA | 4 | Yes |
| 2 | NA | NA | NA | 4 | NA | NA | NA | 6 | No |
| 3 | 1 | NA | 3 | 4 | 5 | NA | NA | 5 | Yes |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 6 | 7 | 9 | No |

Comment: Kindly provide a reproducible dataset via `dput()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version with pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(ID, Follow.up_month)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Follow_up_status = ifelse(Follow.up_month %in% value, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
```

output:

```
     ID Follow.up_month Follow_up_status   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May  June   Jul
  <int>           <int> <chr>            <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1               4 Yes                 NA     2     3     4    NA    NA    NA
2     2               6 No                  NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA    NA
3     3               5 Yes                  1    NA     3     4     5    NA    NA
4     4               9 No                  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     6     7
```

Comment: Nice! I *am* curious: what's the tradeoff between `rowwise()` on the one hand and a `group_by()` with two `pivot_*()`s on the other?

Comment: Thank you! What if I also want to create a column that pulls the column(s) names that match?

Comment: Maybe something like: `df %>% 
  mutate(across(Jan:Jul, ~case_when(Follow.up_month %in% . ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')`

Comment: Thank you TarJae, I will try that. The one issue I am running into with the original code here is that some of the "Follow up months" are "NA", so it is saying "Yes" for "Follow up status" when really it should say NA. How do I incorporate a !is.na statement into this code?

Comment: Try this: `df %>%    mutate(across(Jan:Jul, ~case_when(!is.na(Follow.up_month) & Follow.up_month %in% . ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%   
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')`

Comment: In this solution I only have one column with all the aggregated data, but not a single column for yes/no follow up status

Comment: OK: `df %>%    mutate(across(Jan:Jul, ~case_when(!is.na(Follow.up_month) & Follow.up_month %in% . ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%   
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Follow2 = if_any(Jan:Jul, ~ . %in% Follow.up_month))`. Note `if_any` solution first was provided by r2evans.

Comment: @TarJae - I am actually running into an issue with this where it is taking other numbers besides just the columns I want to pull from. Additionally, it's dropping other variables that I need that are not in the "Jan:Jul" selection. Any suggestions?

Comment: Dear Sophia. I tried the above code and it worked. But maybe it is best if you start a new question referring to this one with your new data. Otherwise we get problems with the place!

Comment: Good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think `rowwise` and `if_any` will work for you:

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    Follow2_int = which(c_across(Jan:Jul) %in% Follow.up.month)[1], 
    Follow2_lgl = !is.na(Follow2_int)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 12
#      ID   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May  June   Jul Follow.up.month Follow_up_Status Follow2_int Follow2_lgl
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>           <int> <chr>                  <int> <lgl>      
# 1     1    NA     2     3     4    NA    NA    NA               4 Yes                        4 TRUE       
# 2     2    NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA    NA               6 No                        NA FALSE      
# 3     3     1    NA     3     4     5    NA    NA               5 Yes                        5 TRUE       
# 4     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     6     7               9 No                        NA FALSE
```

**Edited** to include both the logical and the *first* column number (counting within `Jan:Jul`) that matches.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Jan = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), Feb = c(2L, NA, NA, NA), Mar = c(3L, NA, 3L, NA), Apr = c(4L, 4L, 4L, NA),     May = c(NA, NA, 5L, NA), June = c(NA, NA, NA, 6L), Jul = c(NA,     NA, NA, 7L), Follow.up.month = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 9L), Follow_up_Status = c("Yes",     "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Nice, beat me to it!  Just remember to include the `mutate()` line (with `if_else()`?) that actually generated `Follow_up_Status`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but ... I recommend using `logical` when making a variable that indicates binary status; I tend to switch variables from `logical` to `character` solely for reporting/table-generation. The overhead is not significant large, to be clear, where `Follow_up_Status == "Yes"` is clear and not too expensive, but ... if follow-on code needs to do something conditionally on that variable, it's much less expensive to do `if_else(Follow2, ...)` than `if_else(Follow_up_Status == "Yes", ...)`.

Comment: Likewise, I always work with `logical` until transforming it for readability (`TRUE` to `"yes"`, etc.) at the very end.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the response. I am curious if there is a way to add to your code to create another column that tells me which column(s) the match came from?

Comment: Here's a first cut on adding that column for you, see `Follow2_int`.

Comment: I think I mean the actual column name that it is coming from once we verified that there is a match. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, and I gave what I'm able to figure out right now.

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(across(Jan:Jul, .fns = ~.x - Follow_up_month == 0)) %>%
  mutate(Follow_up_status = as.character(rowSums(select(., Jan:Jul), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  transmute(Follow_up_status = recode(Follow_up_status, "0" = "No", "1" = "Yes")) %>%
  bind_cols(dat, .)
dat2
#   ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May June Jul Follow_up_month Follow_up_status
# 1  1  NA   2   3   4  NA   NA  NA               4              Yes
# 2  2  NA  NA  NA   4  NA   NA  NA               6               No
# 3  3   1  NA   3   4   5   NA  NA               5              Yes
# 4  4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    6   7               9               No
```

**Date**

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Jan = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), Feb = c(2L, NA, NA, NA), Mar = c(3L, NA, 3L, NA), Apr = c(4L, 4L, 4L, NA),     May = c(NA, NA, 5L, NA), June = c(NA, NA, NA, 6L), Jul = c(NA,     NA, NA, 7L), Follow_up_month = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

**Performance**

When the data frame is small, all the solutions here will work. But when data frame is large, the pivoting approach and the rowwise approach may be slow. Below I tried to show the performance comparison of the three solutions. Although the final outputs are different, with different data type and column order, I will still compare them, assuming that these differences are acceptable.

Here is the setup.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


pivot_fun <- function(x){
  x2 <- x %>%
    pivot_longer(
      -c(ID, Follow_up_month)
    ) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Follow_up_status = ifelse(Follow_up_month %in% value, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = name,
      values_from = value
    )
  return(x2)
}

rowwise_fun <- function(x){
  x2 <- x %>%
    pivot_longer(
      -c(ID, Follow_up_month)
    ) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Follow_up_status = ifelse(Follow_up_month %in% value, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = name,
      values_from = value
    )
  return(x2)
}

rowSums_fun <- function(x){
  x2 <- x %>%
    mutate(across(Jan:Jul, .fns = ~.x - Follow_up_month == 0)) %>%
    mutate(Follow_up_status = as.character(rowSums(select(., Jan:Jul), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    transmute(Follow_up_status = recode(Follow_up_status, "0" = "No", "1" = "Yes")) %>%
    bind_cols(x, .)
  return(x2)
}
```

Here is the comparison on the original example. The solution provided in this post is the fastest.

```
set.seed(1)

microbenchmark(pivot_fun(dat), rowwise_fun(dat), rowSums_fun(dat))
# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq     max neval
#   pivot_fun(dat) 11.037401 11.927201 13.58003 12.659001 13.882151 30.0207   100
# rowwise_fun(dat) 10.907602 11.670701 13.56004 12.295051 13.614201 24.4249   100
# rowSums_fun(dat)  6.590502  7.147702  8.48469  7.714351  8.808602 17.0109   100
```

And here is a comparison on a larger data frame. The solution provided in this post is about 10 times faster than other answers.

```
set.seed(12)

n <- 100000

dat_n <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:n,
  Jan = sample(dat$Jan, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Feb = sample(dat$Feb, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Mar = sample(dat$Mar, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Apr = sample(dat$Apr, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  May = sample(dat$May, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  June = sample(dat$June, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Jul = sample(dat$Jul, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  Follow_up_month = sample(1:12, size = n, replace = TRUE)
)

set.seed(123)

microbenchmark(pivot_fun(dat_n), rowwise_fun(dat_n), rowSums_fun(dat_n))
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   pivot_fun(dat_n) 1168.416 1405.5724 1496.6545 1471.0253 1574.3927 2327.1624   100
# rowwise_fun(dat_n) 1159.790 1401.0586 1494.9987 1465.8929 1580.0092 1982.5099   100
# rowSums_fun(dat_n)   84.494  102.0946  122.2843  111.8158  123.6288  296.3234   100
```